# Dynamic filter in list view -> Changing the operator

Tags: 2013, list-view, filter, filtermulivalue

Very simple question, the list view dynamic filter (The one you see when you click on a column header), uses the OR operator for a multi-value field. However, I want to use the AND operator instead.

In other words, there are three items with a mult-value field.

1. Chris, Jack, Joe
2. Chris, Joe
3. Chris

When I filter with Chris and Joe, I see all three (It filters Chris OR Joe)

However, I'd like to see only 1 and 2 (Filtering Chris AND Joe).

Any way how to do this?

I'm using SP 2013. I'm a developer so any (clientside) solution is fine.

Comment: Christoffel, You may need to create a web part or application page to allow for this flexibility. I'm still researching, but it's all I'm aware of thus far.

Comment: Similar post that may help.
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88349/filter-a-multiple-selection-list-box-in-sharepoint

Comment: To your original answer: Sadly, not an option as this is for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Did the link I sent you help at all?

Comment: Sort of, using REST is possible. Though I wish there would be an easier way of doing this. I've been trying to work with URL querystring manipulation, to add the field twice in the querystring with seperate values instead of the ;.